# CAML query with nested ANDs and ORs for multiple fields

Tags: sharepoint, caml, subquery

I am working on proof-of-concept code to dynamically generate CAML based on keywords provided to a highly-specific search web service that I am writing. I am not using the SharePoint-provided search web service for this proof. I have done so already for what I am trying to achieve. From all of my research, I cannot find a close example for what I am trying to achieve, which is to check multiple fields for multiple values. Yes, I have looked on SO already for my answer, including this one: [Need help on building CAML Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255143/need-help-on-building-caml-query).

With that said, if it is possible, how can the following SQL-like query be written in CAML?

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Description, Profile
FROM SomeFakeTable
WHERE (FirstName = 'John' OR LastName = 'John' OR Description = 'John' OR Profile='John')
  AND (FirstName = 'Doe' OR LastName = 'Doe' OR Description = 'Doe' OR Profile='Doe')
  AND (FirstName = '123' OR LastName = '123' OR Description = '123' OR Profile='123')
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Since you are not allowed to put more than two conditions in one condition group (And | Or) you have to create an extra nested group ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms196939.aspx)). The expression `A AND B AND C` looks like this:

```
<And>
    A
    <And>
        B
        C
    </And>
</And>
```

Your SQL like sample translated to CAML (hopefully with matching XML tags ;) ):

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='FirstName' />
                <Value Type='Text'>John</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='LastName' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>John</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Profile' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>John</Value>
                </Eq>
            </Or>
        </Or>
        <And>       
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='FirstName' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>Doe</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Or>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='LastName' />
                        <Value Type='Text'>Doe</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Profile' />
                        <Value Type='Text'>Doe</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Or>
            </Or>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='FirstName' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>123</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Or>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='LastName' />
                        <Value Type='Text'>123</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Profile' />
                        <Value Type='Text'>123</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Or>
            </Or>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason! I came back to visit my question to provide an answer, because I figured it out myself. However, I am just as delighted to see your answer matches my results and very thankful that you took the time to help me and other SO users out.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Your example XML provides a nice way to double check nested syntax. I used it to come up with this method of generating an [equivalent to the In operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198161/caml-in-operator-equivalent-for-sharepoint-services-3-sharepoint-2007)

Answer (score 0):

You can try U2U Query Builder http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx you can use their API U2U.SharePoint.CAML.Server.dll and U2U.SharePoint.CAML.Client.dll

I didn't use them but I'm sure it will help you achieving your task.

Comment: You should not post a solution here unless you know that it can provide the result requested. Using the U2U tool is a great time saver, but you should provide a working example of the code that it generates.

Answer (score 0):

This code will dynamically generate the expression for you with the nested clauses. I have a scenario where the number of "OR" s was unknown, so I'm using the below. Usage:

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var query = new PropertyString(@"<Query><Where>{{WhereClauses}}</Where></Query>");
            var whereClause =
                new PropertyString(@"<Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Counter'>{{NestClauseValue}}</Value></Eq>");
            var andClause = new PropertyString("<Or>{{FirstExpression}}{{SecondExpression}}</Or>");

            string[] values = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};

            query["WhereClauses"] = NestEq(whereClause, andClause, values);

            Console.WriteLine(query);
        }
```

And here's the code:

```
   private static string MakeExpression(PropertyString nestClause, string value)
        {
            var expr = nestClause.New();
            expr["NestClauseValue"] = value;
            return expr.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Recursively nests the clause with the nesting expression, until nestClauseValue is empty.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="whereClause"> A property string in the following format: <Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>{{NestClauseValue}}</Value></Eq>"; </param>
        /// <param name="nestingExpression"> A property string in the following format: <And>{{FirstExpression}}{{SecondExpression}}</And> </param>
        /// <param name="nestClauseValues">A string value which NestClauseValue will be filled in with.</param>
        public static string NestEq(PropertyString whereClause, PropertyString nestingExpression, string[] nestClauseValues, int pos=0)
        {
            if (pos > nestClauseValues.Length)
            {
                return "";
            }

            if (nestClauseValues.Length == 1)
            {
                return MakeExpression(whereClause, nestClauseValues[0]);
            }

            var expr = nestingExpression.New();
            if (pos == nestClauseValues.Length - 2)
            {
                expr["FirstExpression"] = MakeExpression(whereClause, nestClauseValues[pos]);
                expr["SecondExpression"] = MakeExpression(whereClause, nestClauseValues[pos + 1]);
                return expr.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                expr["FirstExpression"] = MakeExpression(whereClause, nestClauseValues[pos]);
                expr["SecondExpression"] = NestEq(whereClause, nestingExpression, nestClauseValues, pos + 1);
                return expr.ToString();
            }
        }






          public class PropertyString
    {
        private string _propStr;

        public PropertyString New()
        {
            return new PropertyString(_propStr );
        }

        public PropertyString(string propStr)
        {
            _propStr = propStr;
            _properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> _properties;
        public string this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                return _properties.ContainsKey(key) ? _properties[key] : string.Empty;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_properties.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    _properties[key] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    _properties.Add(key, value);
                }
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Replaces properties in the format {{propertyName}} in the source string with values from KeyValuePairPropertiesDictionarysupplied dictionary.nce you've set a property it's replaced in the string and you 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="originalStr"></param>
        /// <param name="keyValuePairPropertiesDictionary"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string modifiedStr = _propStr;
            foreach (var keyvaluePair in _properties)
            {
                modifiedStr = modifiedStr.Replace("{{" + keyvaluePair.Key + "}}", keyvaluePair.Value);
            }

            return modifiedStr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you searched for nested or caml query limit ? Can cause issue on this code.