# Nested CAML Query for 6 parameters

Tags: nested, caml

I have one search page.
page have 6 textboxes as a search criteria which user should fill.
According to those 6 textboxes I want to make search on Document library.
The sql query for same will be like this =>

SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE NAME="xyz" or CLIENT="abc" or ADDRESS="lmn" or ROLE="wxy" or STATUS="nop" or AUTHOR="efg";

Please tell me how to write CAML Query for this.
Please share if you have any link to understand nested caml query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question with more parameters. The question with an answer is here: [CAML query with nested AND's and OR's for multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203821/caml-query-with-nested-ands-and-ors-for-multiple-fields)