# Querying Sharepoint with SOAP for null values in multipe fields

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, soap, caml

I am trying to query Sharepoint with SOAP in Powershell but am running into issues when I add more than 2 fields.  What I am wondering is if there is a way to see if any of the 4 fields are Null?

When I execute this query, I get results:

```
<Query>
 <Where>
  <Or>
   <IsNull>
    <FieldRef Name='Field1'/>
   </IsNull>
   <IsNull>
    <FieldRef Name='Field2'/>
   </IsNull>
  </Or>
 </Where>
</Query>
```

However, when I execute this query, an exception is thrown.

```
<Query>
 <Where>
  <Or>
   <IsNull>
    <FieldRef Name='Field1'/>
   </IsNull>
   <IsNull>
    <FieldRef Name='Field2'/>
   </IsNull>
   <IsNull>
    <FieldRef Name='Field3'/>
   </IsNull>
   <IsNull>
    <FieldRef Name='Field4'/>
   </IsNull>
  </Or>
 </Where>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CAML query is malformed. An OR tag cannot contain more than two fields, so any further fields have to be nested.

```xml
<OR >
    FEILD 4
    < OR >
        FEILD 3
        < OR >
            FELD 1
            FELD 2
        < /OR > 
    < /OR >
</ OR >
```

Try CAML query helper
http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is exactly what I was needing.  I tried several nesting options, but this one did the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to mix AND's with your OR's. For Example:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <IsNull>
                <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
            </IsNull>
            <IsNull>
                <FieldRef Name='Field2' />
            </IsNull>
        </Or>
        <And>
            <Or>
                <IsNull>
                    <FieldRef Name='Field3' />
                </IsNull>
                <IsNull>
                    <FieldRef Name='Field4' />
                </IsNull>
            </Or>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```

[CAML query with nested AND's and OR's for multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203821/caml-query-with-nested-ands-and-ors-for-multiple-fields)

Comment: I've tried working with this one several times, but it keeps throwing an exception.  However, the other answer with nested Or's seems to be working.